# 1px chrome error with slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, slider

I have a funny error, which only happens in Chrome... If you take a look at this page:
http://forbrugsforeningen.build.dis-play.dk/Om-Forbrugsforeningen

Then if you use the slider, take a look a the top menu, it sort a jumps 1px during the sliding animation? Haven't seen this before, and even stranger, it's two separate elements on the page, laying in different containers?

The code for the slider is:

```
if ($jq('.rotator').length) {
    $jq('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
        slideDirection: "horizontal",   //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
        slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
        animationDuration: 400,         //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
        directionNav: true,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
        controlNav: true,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
        keyboardNav: false,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
        mousewheel: false,              //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via mousewheel
        prevText: "Tilbage",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
        nextText: "Frem",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
        pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
        pauseText: 'Pause',             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
        playText: 'Afspil slider',               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item
        randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
        slideToStart: 0,                //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
        animationLoop: true,            //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
        pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
        pauseOnHover: false            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
    });
}
```

Comment: Your site seems to be IP restricted.

Comment: Your site shows :- `HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden
The IP address from which you are browsing is not permitted to access the requested Web site.`

Comment: +1... HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Image elements inside the slider should have their position set to relative.

```
#slider li img {
position: relative;
}
```